# Am not understanding how the index() line work

Tags: python

I just not understand how that line of code work

```
p1 = input("enter the play user1")
p2 = input("enter the play user2")
choice = list(['paper', 'rock', 'scissors'])

if p1 not in choice:
    print("dont u know the game")

if p2 not in choice:
    print("dont u know the game")

if p1==p2:
    print("its a draw")

if choice.index(p1) == (choice.index(p2)+1)%3:
    print("player 2 wins")

if choice.index(p2) == (choice.index(p1)+1)%3:
    print("player 1 wins")
```

Comment: I am not understanding what your question is. Do you know what `index()` does?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you're trying to do, but likely `choice[0]` (which returns 'paper') is all you need.

Comment: What type is `choice`? Read the documentation of that type! Hint: You can explore an object in the interactive CLI interface using e.g. the `help()` function and the `dir()` function.

Comment: agree with @mark Ransom.please provide more information.but index itself will return key of element inside array.

Comment: It seems as if its using some weird modulo logic to reconcile the ranking of the moves to determine who wins. Not quite following the logic there.

Comment: if choice.index(p1) == (choice.index(p2)+1)%3: what i was referring to was this code what it does and how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`choice.index(p1) == (choice.index(p2) + 1)` is true when the position of `p2` in the list is one more than the position of `p1` in the list, i.e. `p2` is right after `p1` in the list.

`choice.index(p1) == (choice.index(p2) + 1) % 3` is the same thing, but it considers the start of the list to come right after the end of the list. The end of the list is index 2 (`choice[2] == 'scissors'`), 2 + 1 is 3, and `3 % 3` is 0 – the start of the list.

The list is arranged so that every choice comes after what it loses to in that way. paper (0), rock (1) – paper beats rock; rock (1), scissors (2) – rock beats scissors; scissors (2), paper (0) – scissors beats paper.

[Modular arithmetic on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)

Answer (score 0):

```
list.index(x[, start[, end]])
Return zero-based index in the list of the first item whose value is equal to x. Raises a ValueError if there is no such item.
```

Anyway:
First - `choice = ['paper', 'rock', 'scissors']` - it is equal `list(['paper', 'rock', 'scissors'])`
Then - please read https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_index.asp